# how to accept special characters and spaces in post method of rest call?

Tags: java, rest

I am using post method of rest call to accept text through URL but special charcters and spaces are not accepted and need to do that.

code-

```
@POST
@Path("/{strg}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public String getResponse(@PathParam("strg") String strg) {}
```

Comment: how long that text is expected to be? Have you considered sending it as part of the post body? ideally, that is the correct thing to do if it is a free text and expected to have special characters. If that is the case I can provide some examples.

Comment: means it is recieving the text but when I am saving it to text file it is not doing if space is there or special character is there

Comment: If it is part of path argument then it will be encoded and also not an ideal way of capturing the free text as part of the URL. URLs cannot have spaces and some special characters. You can pass that using post body.

Comment: For Retrofit Android I use this : 
  
    Call<ResponseBody> getMethod(@Url String extra, @HeaderMap ImmutableMap<String, String> headers);

Answer (score 0):

You should not sent special characters thrue path variable. In your case you should pass data in body.

```
`@POST
@Path("/add")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)public String getResponse(@RequestBody String 
bodyString) {}`
```